# Spectral projection with height less than $\lambda$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $x\geq 0$ be a positive element in a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal M.$ Then b y functional calculus the projection $e_\lambda=1_{[0.\lambda)}(x)$ has the property that $e_\lambda$ commutes with $x$ and $e_\lambda x e_\lambda<\lambda.$ Does this characterize $e_\lambda$? That is if $e$ is the largest projection which commutes with $x$ and $exe<\lambda$ , do we have that $e=e_\lambda$?

Comment: Certainly not. The spectral projection onto any subset of $[0,\lambda)$ has the same property. Or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question. The new assumption on e is that it has to be the largest.